# Save log to a file when the default logging output is console

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
```

for logging. By default it goes to console. 
Is it possible to add an option to save this existing log to a file in case of a positive answer? Like it goes to console but in case of an exception there is an option in exception handling function to save log to a file.

Also I wonder is it safe for hdd to write multiple log lines every second?

Answer (score 0):

you can have quite complex logging structure. You can log onto console and in the file directly. You can have multiple logging handlers that have different formatting and logging levels (e.g. you log everything on console, but only errors to a file)

just read the docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html